# Cambiar los valores de una columna de un dataframe para que tengan todos el mismo formato usando regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una columna llamada 'Dates' en mi dataframe,y los datos son distintos en algunos incluso están vacíos,lo primero de todo como veo cuantos los valores que tienen el mismo formato?Cómo cambio los datos con regex para que sean iguales?He probado con esto,`df[['day','month','year']]=df['Date'].str.split('/', expand=True)`,pero me da un ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo este dataframe de ejemplo:

```py
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Dates": ["2019/09/13", "2020-08-13", "", "2021 11 01", np.nan]
    }
)
```

Podríamos definir la siguiente función. Esta función recibe un string con una fecha en formato "**yyyy/mm/dd**", "**yyyy-mm-dd**" o "**yyyy mm dd**" y devuelve la fecha siempre en el mismo formato (en este caso, "**yyyy/mm/dd**"). Esta función usa una **expresión regular**, por lo que para aceptar más formatos de entrada, habría que modificar dicha expresión regular.

```py
def get_formatted_date(x):
    formatted_date = ""
    
    if pd.isna(x):
        return formatted_date

    regex = r"(?P<year>[0-9]{4})(/|-| )(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})(/|-| )(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})"
    match = re.match(regex, x)
    
    if match is not None:
        groups = match.groupdict()
        
        year = groups["year"]
        month = groups["month"].zfill(2)
        day = groups["day"].zfill(2)
        
        # Devolvemos la fecha en el formato que queramos
        formatted_date = f"{year}/{month}/{day}"
    
    return formatted_date
```

Finalmente, reemplazamos la columna **Date** por el resultado de aplicar nuestra función a dicha columna:

```py
df["Dates"] = df["Dates"].apply(get_formatted_date)
```

El dataframe quedaría así:

```
        Dates
0  2019/09/13
1  2020/08/13
2            
3  2021/11/01
4
```

Ten en cuenta que usar `apply` y expresiones regulares puede ser muy poco eficiente si el tamaño del dataframe es grande.

Una alternativa a las expresiones regulares podría ser el método `strptime` de la clase `datetime` del módulo [**datetime**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). Este método devuelve un objeto *datetime* a partir de un **string** y de unos **códigos** de formato específicos y el objeto *datetime* se puede convertir a otro string con el formato que quieras. Pero este método también parsea el texto, por lo que quizás no suponga una ventaja.

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581184/13893607) hay una respuesta (en inglés) a otra pregunta de Stack Overflow, donde se usa el método `strptime`. Aunque en esta respuesta se usan excepciones para controlar el flujo del programa y eso creo que se considera una mala práctica.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!Genial explicado!!cuál crees que sería la forma más eficiente para que todos los valores de la columna sigan el mismo formato sin usar regex??

Comment: De nada, me alegra haber ayudado. He editado mi respuesta para explicar una alternativa a las expresiones regulares, pero no creo que suponga una gran ventaja en cuanto a eficiencia, porque el texto se parsea igualmente. No conozco ninguna forma más eficiente, lo siento. En cualquier caso, lo ideal sería que, desde el principio, las fechas se almacenaran con el mismo formato para evitar problemas, convirtiéndolas previamente al formato correcto si fuese necesario.